# If $f_n\leq g_n \leq h_n$, $f_n \to f$, $h_n \to h$ pointwise and $\int f_n\to\int f$,$\int h_n \to \int h$ then prove that $\int g_n \to \int g$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

[image]

The problem is not properly stated in the original, here is the correct version:
If $f_n\leq g_n \leq h_n$, $f_n \to f$, $h_n \to h$ pointwise and $\int f_n\to\int f$,$\int h_n \to \int h$ then $\int g_n \to \int g$

Really do not know to how to tackle this problem. it is easy to show that $g \in L^1$. But not sure how to show convergence of integrals. The only thing I see is that $|g_n|\leq \max\{-f_n,h_n\}$ but that is not very helpful. I tried applying generalized dominated convergence theorem but could not succeed. Not sure what else to try. I was wondering if perhaps these conditions somehow imply that all of them converge in $L^1$ Any hints or solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: What does $\int g_n \to g$ mean? Where is this taken from?

Comment: @copper.hat I assume that is an error in the original. The title has it correct. Let me fix this.

Comment: What book is it from?

Comment: @copper.hat I have seen it on two past quals form different schools, so no book reference unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$0 \le g_n - f_n \le h_n -f_n$, so $g_n-f_n$ is dominated by the integrable $h_n-f_n$. Hence $g-f$ is integrable and $\int(g_n-f_n) \to \int (g-f)$.
Adding $f_n, f$ to each side gives the desired result.

**Alternative:**

To original intent here was to avoid the generalised DCT 
but it just ended up being a marginal variation of said theorem.

We have $\int \varliminf (g_n -f_n) \le \int \varliminf (h_n -f_n) \le \varliminf \int (h_n -f_n) = \int (h-f)$. Since $\varliminf (g_n-f_n) = g-f$ ae. we see that $g \in L^1$.

Note that $\int \varliminf (g_n -f_n) \le \varliminf \int (g_n-f_n) = \varliminf (\int g_n - \int f)$ which gives
$\int g \le \varliminf \int g_n$. Similarly, $\int \varliminf (h_n -g_n) \le \varliminf \int (h_n-g_n) = \varliminf (\int h - \int g_n)$ which gives
$\varlimsup \int g_n \le \int g$.

Comment: wow, cant believe I did not think of that.  Thank you very much. I was wracking my brain on this problem for a while, over complicating it.... Could you tell me what made you think to do that, or did you just instinctively do it and it worked?

Comment: I just looked for a way to apply the DCT. Since I didn't have sign information, I looked to see if I could make it non negative.

Comment: For the DCT don't we need that the sequence is dominated by a fixed integrable function?

Comment: @stochasticboy321 he probably means Generalized DCT in this case as i mention in my question.

Comment: @Sorfosh Oh cool. I've either forgotten this or never read it, so thanks for the name of the theorem!

Comment: I think it should be possible without big guns, let me think a while before too much wine permeates my gray matter. I'm thinking Fatou's lemma.

Comment: If you have limited memory like myself, I would pack Fatou's lemma in my brain space rather than the generalised DCT :-).

Comment: @copper.hat I compensate my lack of ingenuity with memory of useful theorems :P Regarding the alternative solution did we not only get that $\liminf \int h_n=\int h$ ? How do we show similarly with limsup?

Comment: We are given $\lim \int h_n = \int h$, so $\liminf = \lim$ here.

Comment: @copper.hat hmm dont you only get that integral of g is less than integral of $h$? sorry could you elaborate a bit more? Is it possible you have a typo in there?

Comment: Sorry, I may have made a mistake. Give me a few more minutes...

Comment: @copper.hat I suspect that a solution involving fatous would simply reprove general DCT

Comment: Yes, 10 pages of scrap suggests that is where I will end up :-(. Hate having to eat crow.

Comment: @Sorfosh: Yep, it just ended up being a tweak of the generalised DCT :-(.